# How to confirm an input using Zenity?

Tags: bash, zenity

I need to display a GUI pop up that shows a message with a variable, and allows user to confirm or cancel.

Perhaps I'm missing something, but I could not find any documentation on Zenity `--questions` tag.  So far I couldn't get anything other than default question to display.

I don't want to use Yad if possible... I would like to stick with Zenity.

Is there any way to do this with Zenity?

Example:

```
var="ABC"
msg="Confirm $var"
zenity --text-info \
    --title="Confirm"
    --text="$msg"
    # --question "This is the question"
case $? in
    0)
        return
    ;;
    1)
        return
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: `zenity --question --title=Confirm --text=hello`

Comment: `echo hello | zenity --text-info --title=Confirm`

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but you're missing a backslash after the `--title` line, so the `--text` line is treated as a command.

Comment: @wjandrea I didn't even see that^^ Well, putting that aside,`--text` doesn't work with `--text-info`; you need to feed the text to display through a file or stdin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
zenity --question --title="Confirm" --text="$msg"
```

It's `--question`, not `--questions`, but in [the Zenity manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zenity), do a Ctrl-F for `question` to find all the relevant sections.